# CodeIgniger File Upload, Unable to spot error

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, upload

I've been trying to uplaod a zip file with Codeigniter, something i've done before but cant seem to get to work this time. Here are my files:

View:

```
<h2>Add a New Album</h2>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/photo/newAlbum">
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td><p>Album Name:</p></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="aName" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p></p></td>
        <td><input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p></p></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Upload Images and Create Gallery" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
        $config['upload_path'] = $path;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'zip';


    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
    {
        $data['message'] = $this->upload->display_errors();

        $this->template->load('admin/template', 'admin/msg', $data);
    }
    else
    { $codeToBeWrittin }
```

The Error:

> You did not select a file to upload.

Comment: Sounds like none of your post data is reaching the controller, try echo var_dump($_POST); and see if you're at least getting the aName field from the form. Start there.

Comment: thanks for the tip, however now i see that when my form has the enctype="multipart form-data", no data goes through. But when I don't add it, post data goes through but no file uploads. Any Idea...

Comment: Have you tried to use CI's form helper to generate the form for a test? `form_open_multipart()`   — http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How big is your file?

I'd check your PHP configuration to see whether your `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` ini file parameters are sufficiently large to handle the upload.

Comment: I had set upload_max_filesize but not post_max_size, Thanks alot :D